# Use only one write stream in parent process for multiple child processes

Tags: node.js, stream, node.js-stream

Say I have multiple node.js child processes, and I want their stdout/stderr to all write to the same file.

In the parent process, ideally I could create one stream to the file, something like so:

```
const cp = require('child_process');
const strm = fs.createWriteStream('bar.log');

async.each([1,2,3], function(item, cb){

 const n = cp.spawn('node', ['foo' + item + '.js']);

 n.stdout.pipe(strm);
 n.stderr.pipe(strm);

 n.on('close', cb);

}, function(err){
 if(err) throw err;
});
```

what will likely happen is that we'll get an error:

```
Error: write after 'end'
```

The following seems to fix the problem, whereby we create a new stream for every child process:

```
const cp = require('child_process');

async.each([1,2,3], function(item, cb){

 const n = cp.spawn('node',['foo' + item + '.js']);

  //create a new stream for every child process...
 const strm = fs.createWriteStream('bar.log');

 n.stdout.pipe(strm);
 n.stderr.pipe(strm);

 n.on('close', cb);

}, function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
});
```

Is there a way to "keep the stream open" even if the child fires the end event?  Seems unnecessary to have to create a new stream for every child process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the resulting stream was not closed for writing you need set the [`end`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options) option to `false`:

```
 n.stdout.pipe(strm, {end: false});
 n.stderr.pipe(strm, {end: false});
```

Comment: Confirmed that this worked, had to use it for something else, thanks!